# DockerコンテナでRailsでアプリを作りたい。docker-composeで出るエラー

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, wsl

WindowsでWSLを用いて、Railsでアプリを作ろうとしています。

コンテナの中で次のコマンドを実行すると、

```
rails new . --force --database=postgresql --skip-bundle
```

Gemfileが更新されるので、install bundleしなくてはなりません。

ですので、containerからexitして次のコマンドを実行しました。

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

すると次のようなエラーが出ました。

```
[+] Building 0.9s (2/3)
[+] Building 1.0s (3/3) FINISHED
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.1s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                0.1s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.1s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                    0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:2.5                                                  0.8s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ruby:2.5:
------
failed to solve: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to create LLB definition: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = error getting credentials - err: exit status 1, out:
```

docker-compose.yml は次のようになっています。

```
version: '3'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    ports:
      - '3000:3000'
    volumes:
      - '.:/product-register'
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

Dockerfile は次のようになっています。

```
FROM ruby:2.5
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    build-essential \
    libpq-dev \
    nodejs \
    postgresql-client \
    yarn

WORKDIR /product-register
COPY Gemfile Gemfile.lock /product-register/
RUN bundle install
```

コンテナの中で、

```
rails new . --force --database=postgresql --skip-bundle
```

を実行する前に行った次のコマンドは上手くいきました。

```
docker-compose up -d
```

このエラーの正体は何でしょうか？

またどのようにするべきでしょうか？

何卒宜しくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

時間を置いて、

```
docker-compose up --build -d
```

をすると何故か上手く動きました。

ありがとうございました。

何か原因がお分かりでしたらコメントを頂けると嬉しいです。

宜しくお願い致します。